# startActivityForResult inside startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

If I call `startActivityForResult` and the activity that starts is also calling `startActivityForResult` on another activity,
is it possible that the first activity will be stopped ?
Is there a way to prevent it from happen?
What context should I pass each intent I create?

some code to figure the process

```
intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, AbstractSettingsActivity.SETTINGS_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

// this is inside the Settings activity
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SettingsTabsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, CUSTOMIZE_TAB_REQUEST_CODE);
// at this point i got ondstroy on main activity - main is not the root
```

Comment: Well, I think it's related to the no history flag on my main activity...

Answer (score 2):

In any case (either its `startActivity` or `startActivityForResult`), when you start a new activity, your current `Activity` will go into **stopped** state by raising its `onStop` method. Its the way [**Android's Activity life-cycle**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) is designed. It has nothing to do with a type of context.

However, if you don't want to occur `onStop`, then perhaps you may try emulating the expected view(s) through [**`Dialogs`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) which will cause your Activity to reach up till its `onPause` state.

Comment: Can I open a dialog inside a dialog? or should the dialog open activities?

Comment: You should proceed with activities if your view requirements are complex. Why do you want to avoid onStop in your parent activity?

Comment: Cause for some strange reason I get to onDestroy... and can't go back to the activity.